# How to repopulate form after form validation and also keep the URI?

Tags: codeigniter, uri

I have a problem repopulating my form after validation fails. Problem is my url contains an additional uri which I access by clicking a link. This is what it looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/trivia/add/5
```

At first trouble was that the segment 4 of the uri completely disappeared, so even though the validation errors showed and the form was repopulated, I lost my added uri.

Then I found in another question that the solution was to set form open like this:

```
echo form_open(current_url());
```

Problem is now it isn't showing any validation errors and the form is not repopulated. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is what my controller looks like:

```
function add()
{       
    $data = array('id' => $this->uri->segment(4));

    if($_POST)
    {
        $this->_processForm();  
    }

    $this->load->view('admin/trivia_form', $data);
}
```

And inside _processForm() I got all the validation rules, error message and redirecting in case success.

[edit] Here is my _processForm() :

```
function _processForm()
{       
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //validation rules go here
    //validation error messages

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:red">', '</div>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        //get input from form and assign it to array            
        //save data in DB with model
        if($this->madmin->save_trivia($fields)) 
        {
            //if save is correct, then redirect 
        }
        else 
        {
            //if not show errors, no redirecting.
        }   

    }//end if validation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the same url, you can do all things in a same controller function.

In your controller

```
function add($id)
{
   if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')// form submitted
   {
      // do form action code
      // redirect if success


   }

   // do your actual stuff to load. you may get validation error in view file as usual if validation failed

}
```

Comment: Do you mean my form_validation->run() should be inside the if? Because I already got something like that, I'll update my question to show you my controller.

Comment: @Ant100 Yes. Inside the if condition. If validation failed, you shouldn't redirect. Just leave it. So current code will load the view with values.

Comment: I'm not redirecting, I'll post the rest of my code so you can see.

Comment: In my view, the error messages do not show, and form doesn't repopulate.

Comment: Remove your else part in _processForm function. Then try. Hope you are showing error message in in your html form.(`validation_errors`).

Comment: Yes I'm using validation_errors and also set_value for repopulation. Removed the else part and still no changes :( It must have something to do with my open_form(current_url()) in it, but if I do it the normal way open_form('admin/trivia/add') I lose the id in the URI.
-- Actually, it just worked. It's strange because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, but I think it has something to do with my hosting when reloading pages, not with code itself. Thanks for your help! I'll accept your answer as it has the right solution.

Comment: @Ant100 Ok. You dont want to set for action. If action is blank, current url will be taken by default. just try `echo form_open('');`.

Answer (score 0):

to repopulate the form fields you are going to need to reset the field values when submitting it as exampled [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform) and to meke it open the same page you can use redirect() function as bellow:

```
redirect('trivia/add/5','refresh');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I'm already using set_value() though, and when I tried redirecting it didn't work I still lost all my validation errors and the form didn't repopulate.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you are trying to do, but try this to repopulate the form with the values user entered

```
<?php
      echo form_input('myfield',set_value('myfield'),'placeholder="xyz"');
?>
```